# drag and drop images to event in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I really hope to get some help with this. I'm doing a calendar for kids using fullcalendar. It should be possible to drag and drop som image icon into the events of the calendar. It looks someting like this:  http://boerne.migraeniker.dk/kalender_filer/default.html
But how can I display the image that I drop inside the event.

The code that should drop the image is here:

```
    drop:function(start,end, allDay) {

    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('event');


    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);


   if (copiedEventObject.title) {


   start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");



  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://boerne.migraeniker.dk/kalender_filer/add_events.php',
  data: 'title='+copiedEventObject.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(json) {

  }
  });



  calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
  {

 title: copiedEventObject.title,
 start: start,
 end: end,
 allDay: allDay
 },
 true // make the event "stick"
 );
 }
 calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
 },
```

I really hope this makes sense otherwise I can post more of the code.

Comment: What's the trouble you're having? Each time you post a question, you should add as much detail as you can, including what's the result and which it should be.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [External dragging demo](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/external-dragging.html)
You need to declare `droppable` and `drop` in $('#mycalendar')

```
droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/igos/U7S6H/)